# Trying to build a 2d array from a text file but the endl char is being placed above the input, is it in the wrong place in my for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, iostream, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to print out a 20/20 array from a text file using standard input (in the command line). When I run my code it is getting printed out in one line, with 19 new lines above the maze chars, whereas the new line should be at the end of each column? Am I doing something wrong/is there an error in the code which I am not seeing? (MAZE_DIM = 20)

```
for(int rows = 0; rows < MAZE_DIM; rows++)
{
    for(int columns = 0; columns < MAZE_DIM; columns++)
    {
        std::cin >> maze[rows][columns];     
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This is the code used to print the input in another function

std::cout << "Print maze below:" << std::endl;

```
if(std::cin.good()){
    std::cout << *maze << std::endl;}
```

This is the output, whereas there should be a new line after the 19th char each row?

Print maze below:
====================S........===================.============......=.=============.=.=...============..=..=.=================.==.================....================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================.==.================E==============

Comment: I don't see any code that adds newlines to `maze`. `std::cout << std::endl;` writes newlines to the console , your mysterious 19 lines,  while inputting the maze data, but none are written to `maze`. Could be elsewhere the code you don't show us, but based on what we can see, the answer is simple: You didn't tell the computer to add newlines so the computer didn't add newlines.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm very new to c++ so sorry to ask a silly question but how would I tell the computer to add the new lines to maze input instead of the console?

Comment: Give each row one extra column. Place a `'\n'` into that extra column.

Comment: Mind you, it looks like you're playing fast and loose with a 2D array and treating as both a 1D and a 2D array. This usually works, but isn't guaranteed by the rules of C++.